# how to show Details(coming from webservice) on the webview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, string, ios, uiwebview

Well..

I am using webservice in a project..

In that I am getting such responce..

"node_revisions_body" = "< p>\ n Text goes here \n < p>

I want to show this response on webview..
I have taken a dictionary for that also..

but i dont know how to show this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about `- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL`